# Drywall work adjacent to painted surfaces - problems with adhesion?

Tags: drywall

If you have to do some drywall work patching into an existing painted surface, are there any special considerations or prep you should do, or will the drywall joint compound generally go right over paint & adhere OK?

This seems like it would be a totally common situation in practically ever renovation / repair scenario.

Assume the painted surface is in perfectly good condition - not flaking or peeling or anything.

In my specific instance the ceiling is flat finished with matte paint, and some drywall work is being done on a wall & its corner where it meets the ceiling.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not usually an issue unless you're dealing with glossy paint or some of the older enamels. If you're concerned, rough it up or spot-prime the painted areas with a good bonding primer and carry on.